# Laravel Admin with controller level permissions

Tags: laravel, permissions, routes, admin, acl

what I want to create is Laravel 5.2 Admin and there are around 200 users who will use it with different permissions, so you can say 200 roles with different permissions.

I was planning to eliminate the role part from the picture and create some slug based mechanism, slugs will be related to controller public functions in short routes.

In Admin panel superuser will be able to assign permissions to user on controller functions with slugs.

Is this possible with any existing laravel package currently? If not then what will be the optimal solution you guys propose.

Comment: Why Laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

I always use Spatie Package, it is very flexible. You can manage role & permissions or only permissions. It is full of functions that make it easy. Check the documentation.

[spatie-laravel-permission](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/)